# How to recover script from closed workspace

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, data-recovery

Sometimes you write a script in a workspace for a long time, and then you exigently close that workspace. Can you recover lost script somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the black triangle in the top right of a new workspace and select `Previous contents...`. This only works if you saved the content of the lost workspace (e.g., using `Ctrl+s`).

Comment: "only works if you saved the content" - not in Pharo3.0 #30850

Answer (score 3):

If not a lot of time ha passed after the workspace was closed, maybe it wasn't collected and the script will be available among:

```
Smalltalk tools workspace allInstances collect: #contents
```